# Is there always a positive projection map from a generic open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I came across a proof where it's used one such map in the following way.
Let $V \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open, non empty, subset - we're using euclidean topology. We consider a projection map $\pi : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x \in V \ \pi(x) \geq 0$.

I just cannot convince myself that one such map always exists. Could anyone please explain why? I would also appreciate an example.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: without further restrictions this is not true. for a silly example, if you take $V = \mathbb R^n$ then for any projection $\pi$ onto $\mathbb R$, we have $\mathbb \pi(V)=\mathbb R$

Comment: Thank you. What if $V \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ ? I've also edited the question.

Comment: it still doesn't work for the unit ball for instance, using the fact that $\pi(-x)=-\pi(x)$

Comment: That doesn't really change anything, take $V=\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Is $\pi$ required to be linear?

Comment: I see what you mean with the unit ball example. What if I consider a generic affine subspace of dimension 1, parametrise it in such a way that the projection of $V$ onto it has its image at the right of $0$? I'm sorry for the way I've put it, but I've just had this idea and I'm wondering whether it might answer my question.

Comment: Can you give a definition of "projection map" in your context please?

Comment: @AlexT If you consider $\Bbb R$ as some specific subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and your (affine) subset of $\Bbb R^n$ intersects this $\Bbb R$ in some negative number, and you consider projections as [idenpotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) (as projections usually are), then there is no such $\pi$.

Comment: @AlexT linear or affine? I think that this is the key point

Comment: Consider $\pi : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $(x_1,\cdots ,x_n) \mapsto \ x_1$. Then a projection map would be any map that can be expressed in this way in some coordinates.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I think affine solves my problem. I am sorry to be so confusing, but I am having a hard time understanding the context of the proof I've mentioned. I'm working with manifolds, so yeah, affine is okay.

Comment: @AlexT Simply affine/linear would be trivial as you always have the map $\pi(x)=0$. Should it be of rank 1 or something?

Comment: @AlexT No, the claim is not even true for affine maps. Consider $V := \Bbb R^n - \{ 0 \}$ with $n > 0$. However, if $V$ is compact, there is (almost trivially) always an affine map $\pi : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ such that $\pi(V) \subset [0, \infty)$.

Comment: @Travis Thank you. Then I suppose I would also need limited open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: @AlexT You're welcome. I suppose the condition you want is that your open subsets should be *precompact*, i.e., that their closure is compact.

Answer (score 3):

There is always the trivial affine map $\pi(v)=0$ which works for all $V$. But if we restrict to rank one maps, we can say the following:

> **Theorem**. Given $V\subset\Bbb R^n$. There exists a rank one affine map $\pi:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ with $\pi(v)\ge 0$ if and only if $V$ is contained in some half-space.

*Proof*.

The rank one affine maps $\pi:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ are exactly the maps $\pi(v)=\langle c,v\rangle-\lambda$ for some non-zero $c\in\Bbb R^n$ and some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. The statement $\pi(v)\ge 0$ is then equivalent to

$$\langle c,v\rangle \ge \lambda,$$

which defines the desired half space.

---

This means that such a "projection" exists if e.g. $V$ is bounded or a proper affine subspace. It does not work e.g. for complements of bounded sets.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=1$ and $V = \mathbb{R}$, then no such map exists.  (Unless projection map doesn't mean what I think it means).

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question, so that this case is excluded.